# how can i pass a variable between functions in the same controller (laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass `$newOrder` to the view(orders.success) in order to be able to print the "receipt" once the order is concluded. Nothing seems to work, i have tried with compact/with methods but it's always undefined since `$newOrder` is declared in another function.
do you have some tips?

```php
    class BraintreeController extends Controller
{

    public function token(Request $request)
    {

        $gateway = new \Braintree\Gateway([
            'environment' => 'sandbox',
            'merchantId' => 'jgvy755pfvwdcjzx',
            'publicKey' => 'qqpm93srfgwtx6dp',
            'privateKey' => 'd13ce21a7642606db73b12bb1300d3fd'
        ]);

        $clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();

        if ($request->input('nonce') != null) {
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'last_name' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required',
                'address' => 'required',
                'email' => 'email:rfc',
            ]);

            //# Storo l'ordine
            $name = $request->input('name');
            $last_name = $request->input('last_name');
            $address = $request->input('address');
            $phone = $request->input('phone');
            $email = $request->input('email');
            $arr_id = $request->input('arr_id');
            $arr_quant = $request->input('arr_quant');
            $delivery_fee = $request->input('delivery_fee');
            //# Recupero tutti i piatti dell'ordine per calcolarne il totale
            $dishes = Dish::findMany($arr_id);
            $arrayLength = count($arr_id);
            $amount = 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++) {
                $amount +=  $dishes[$i]->price * $arr_quant[$i];
            }
            $amount += $delivery_fee;

            //#


            $newOrder = new Order();
            $newOrder->status = 1;
            $newOrder->address = $address;
            $newOrder->user_name = $name;
            $newOrder->user_surname = $last_name;
            $newOrder->phone = $phone;
            $newOrder->email = $email;
            $newOrder->total = $amount;
            $newOrder->save();

            // // storo l'array di IDs


            // Ciclo una volta per ogni piatto contenuto nell'ordine, salvo la relazione e la sua quantità
            for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++) {
                $dish_id = $arr_id[$i];
                // Scrive nella tabella pivot dopo aver creato la relazione
                $newOrder->dishes()->attach([$dish_id => ['quantity' => $arr_quant[$i]]]);
                //
            }

            //#


            var_dump($request->input('nonce'));
            $nonceFromTheClient = $request->input('nonce');
            $gateway->transaction()->sale([
                'amount' => $amount,
                'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonceFromTheClient,
                'options' => [
                    'submitForSettlement' => True
                ]
            ]);


            Mail::to($email)->send(new PaymentConfirmationMail());
            return view('orders.success');
        }


        return view('orders.braintree', ['token' => $clientToken]);
    }

    public function success(Request $request)
    {
        return view('orders.success');
    }
}
```

this is the view where i try to print the receipt

```
<body>
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5 text-center">
    <h1>Pagamento avvenuto con successo</h1>
    <h2 class="mb-5">il tuo ordine è stato preso in carico</h2>
    <a href="{{route('restaurants.index')}}">Ritorna ai ristoranti</a>
    <h1>{{$newOrder->address}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the new order that you've just saved?  If so, you can just query it by `$getTheNewOrder = Order::where('status', '=', 1)->where('address', '=', $request->address)->where('user_name', '=', $request->name)->where('user_surname', '=', $request->last_name)->where('phone', '=', $request->phone)->where('email', '=', $request->email)->latest()->first();`. Add this before `return view('orders.success');` and make sure you edit your return view with `return view('orders.success', compact('getTheNewOrder'));`

Comment: yes the goal is to retrieve the new order. tried your solution but $getTheNewOrder is still null...

Comment: You should include the query I mentioned inside your `token` function so that it still retains the `$request` values used in the `$getTheNewOrder` query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new PaymentConfirmationMail());
return view('orders.success',['newOrder' => $newOrder]);
```

Or change params on success function like this

```
public function success($newOrder)
{
    return view('orders.success', ['newOrder' => $newOrder]);
}
```

And return from previews function

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new PaymentConfirmationMail());
return $this->success($newOrder);
```

Comment: applying the first solution $newOrder is still undefined, while the second gives the error "Too few arguments to function success(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected". thank you very much anyway for trying to help me!

Comment: can you post a repo link for see your project on Github or Gitlab? without the entire code anyone can help you